# Terminate Scipy solve_ivp on custom predicate

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have an ODE `dy/dt = f(y,t)`, where y is a N dimensional vector, which I would like to solve using the `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` function.

However, I would like to stop the integration if a certain predicate `g(y,t)` evaluates to True. The use case I have here is that I expect the value of `y` to converge towards some constant value `y0` before the end of the integration duration `t_end`. I am interested in this constant value `y0` and would like to save time by terminating the integration once convergence has happened.

I was hoping that I could create an array to store the values of `y` in the last 5 integration steps, and if they are very close, convergence is believed to have happened.

The `event` function of `solve_ivp` does not really help in my case: there is no root that I hope to find, and I am not interested in the `t` when convergence happens. I am surprised that this seemingly "common" use case of looking for a convergence cannot be done easily, and I can't find similar problems already on Stackoverflow.

If someone has some idea, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Why does the `events` argument not work? Can't you modify `g` to return `False` instead of `True` (which will effectively be returning zero when you want it to stop)

Comment: `events` callable(s) do not get a history of the solution just the current values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for accessing the integrator classes that `solve_ivp` uses under the hood.  If we take the simple function  `dy/dt = -y` with initial condition `y(0) = 100`.  We want to terminate the function when the solution has changed by less than 0.1 over 1 second of simulation, i.e. `abs(y(t) - y(t-1)) < 0.1`.  For this ODE, this occurs at `t=-ln(0.1 / (100(e-1))` or `t~7.45`.  We can solve this using RK45 integrator ([RK45 docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html)) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import RK45
def fun(t, y):
    return -y
    
y0 = [100]
t0 = 0

#max_step used to ensure that we take small enough time steps
rk45 = RK45(fun, t0, y0, t_bound=1000, max_step=0.1)
t = []
y = []
while rk45.status == "running":
    t.append(rk45.t)
    y.append(rk45.y[0])
    if rk45.t > 1.0 and np.abs(np.interp(rk45.t-1, t, y) - rk45.y[0]) < 0.1:
        break
    rk45.step()

print(f"Final t: {t[-1]:.1f}")

# Because max_step=0.1, t[-11] will be 1 second behind t[-1]
print(f"Time period checked: {t[-1]-t[-11]:.1f}, delta_y: {y[-11]-y[-1]:.1f}")
```

yields

```
Final t: 7.5
Time period checked: 1.0, delta_y: 0.1
```